# what is the best way to iterate a list and exit in java

Tags: java, collections

I have an list of students object; I want to find out if at least one student have valid ID or not. if all of them in the list have a invalid ID or blank ID then I should exist and throw an exception. What is the best way of doing it in JAVA ?

Example

```
    List<Student> Students;
    class Student {
    int ID;
    String Name;
    int Marks;
    }

    Student one
    ID = 1,name = Ram,Marks = 50

    Student two
    ID = "",name = Syam,Marks = 60

    Student three
    ID = 2,name = Sudan,Marks = 70
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This sounds like a code request

Comment: I am iterating the array list and with a if condition where at least one of the students ID is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean isAllInvalid= true;
for(Student student : students){ 
 if(student.getID() != null && studend.getID() >=1 ){// this checks for a valid id 
  system.out.print(student+ " has a valid id");
  isAllInvalid =false; 
  break;//early exit no need to keep looping cuz we found at least one valid id ,if you to print all valid remove the break statement.
 } 
}
 if(isAllInvalid){
   throw new SomeException("All students are invalid") ;//choose ur suitable exception
 }
```

Comment: here is simple for each  loop

Comment: It would be better to throw a runtime exception such as `IllegalArgumentException` or `IllegalStateException`; in general, `Exception` should never be thrown.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. It throws an Exception it *any* student has an invalid id. The OP wants to only have the Exception if *all* student ids are invalid.

Comment: Stefan you are correct this is not what I wanted. the code has to throw an exception only if all the students do not have a valid ID.

Comment: I have commented //it is better to use your custom Exception some subclass of exception of what ever

Comment: oh ok sorry I did not notice all I will update to to check that Students have invalid ids

Comment: Thanks Amjad for updating the code snippet. This is what I am looking for its working and I implemented it.

Is there any other way of doing it ?

Comment: if there is another way it would be as Mureinik mentioned using streaming
,which hides a iteration loop or condition at back seen ,it is just another simpler and briefer way to code :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some method to check the ID's validity, the easiest would probably be to use Java 8's streaming capabilities:

```
List<Student> students = ...;
boolean hasValid = students.stream().anyMatch(s -> isValid(s.getId()));
```

EDIT:
If you aren't using Java 8, you could always create the same behavior by looping over the list and stopping once you encounter a valid student:

```
private static boolean hasValidStudent(Collection<Student> students) {
    for (Student s : students) {
        if (isValid(s.getId()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am using java 7 and lower. can you suggest how to implement in Java 7 and lower versions.

Comment: @Santosh if you're still in Java 7, you could just loop over them. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Student> students = ...
boolean anyValid = false;
for (Student student : students) {
    anyValid = anyValid || isValid(student.getId());
}
if (!anyValid) {
    // throw proper Exception
}
```

Comment: If you really need to exit when the condition is met you need to replace the foreach with an Iterator:
    Iterator<Student> studentsIterator = students.iterator();
    while(!anyValid && studentsIterator.hasNext()){
        anyValid = anyValid || isValid(studentsIterator.next().getId());}